# Since my root directory is getting bigger, can I install deb packages using home directory?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am getting the root directory bigger and bigger, here are some evidences for my 25G root directory.

I feel like there are some folders I can delete or move to Home directory but I do not know how to. Is it also possible to install .deb packages under home directory? I tried with the following command but I failed in launching the software.

`dpkg-deb -x /home/Alessio/Downloads/EdrawMax_12.0.6_en.deb /home/Alessio/Edrawmax/`

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Please note in that answer that extracting the package is **not** the same as installing it.  If you install if, it must go to the directories as dictated by the packager (ie. you control what drive/partition those directories are stored on, but only control the package if you create your own packages; ie. extract & rebuild so it uses different directories).

Comment: Please do not place essential information for your question on Imgur or similar locations where it may be gone when someone later consults this question and its answers.

Comment: Also, the pictures on Imgur do *not* show a 25G root directory. They seem to show a total occupied space of 19.7G on your root filesystem, including all subdirectories. Please show output of `df` command to give information about your disk occupancy.